# sqlite doesn't work after uprade cordova to 2.3.0

Tags: jquery, sqlite, cordova

After upgrading the cordova version to 2.3.0, my sqlite plugin isn't work.
I didn't change the implementation. The reference in the config.xml file exists also.

Is there a new sqlite plugin version?